# Symfony2: losing session variables after redirect

Tags: php, symfony

I have website which have three different translations, by default it is english, each translation is placed under his own subdomain. What I am trying to do, is redirect from subdomain de.mydomain.com to mydomain.com and set the translation's language in session variable named "locale", but the problem is that after redirection this session's variable disappears

config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        lifetime:       3600
        cookie_domain: .mydomain
```

SubdomainListener:

```
class SubdomainListener
    {
        protected $domain;
        /* @var Translator */
        protected $translator;
        /* @var Router */
        protected $router;

        public function __construct($domain, $translator, $router)
        {
            $this->domain = $domain;
            $this->translator = $translator;
            $this->router = $router;
        }

        public function onDomainParse(GetResponseEvent $event)
        {

            if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
                // don't do anything if it's not the master request
                return;
            }
            /* @var $request Request */
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            /* @var $session Session */
            $session = $request->getSession();

            $host = $request->getHost();
            $subDomain = str_replace($this->domain, '', $host);
            $supportedTranslations = array('pl_PL', 'en_US', 'de_DE');
            $preferredLanguage = $request->getPreferredLanguage();
            if (!in_array($preferredLanguage, $supportedTranslations)) {
                $preferredLanguage = 'en_US';
            }

            if (strlen($subDomain) > 0) {
                if ($subDomain == "pl.") {
                    $preferredLanguage = "pl_PL";
                } elseif ($subDomain == "en.") {
                    $preferredLanguage = "en_US";
                } elseif ($subDomain == "de.") {
                    $preferredLanguage = "de_DE";
                }

                $route = $request->get('_route');
                $routeParams = $request->get('_route_params');
                if (strpos($route, '_sd') === false) {
                    $route = $route . '_sd';
                }
                $url = $this->router->generate($route, $routeParams);

                $session->set('redirected', 1);
                $session->set('locale', $preferredLanguage);
                $this->translator->setLocale($preferredLanguage);
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url, 301));
            }
            if (!$session->get('redirected')) {
                $session->set('locale', $preferredLanguage);
                $this->translator->setLocale($preferredLanguage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May you post code, how you redirect and your config.yml?

Comment: `_locale` not `locale`

Comment: I am aware that, but this problem does not affect only this variable

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this "loss" is probably a usage of a non-domain cookie.

To turn this feature on you should specify your domain in the config. According to [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-domain), for `2.2` and `2.1` versions of Symfony:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .yoursite.com
```

Comment: sorry but your tip does not change anything for me

Comment: @dwilda Are you sure, you are using a second level domain for testing too? Eg `myapp.local` and expanded `(en|de|pl).myapp.local`? Browsers don't allow setting a cookie_domain for a tld (eg `.mydomain` only) so you must use a second level domain with subdomains!

Comment: @Pazi Nice one! Sharp-eye ;)